# quarkus maven plugin fails to create a project

Tags: java, maven, quarkus, sample

Trying to create a quarkus project from scratch with the command:

```
mvn io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.13.7.Final:create -DprojectGroupId=org.acme -DprojectArtifactId=getting-started -DclassName="org.acme.getting.started.GreetingResource" -Dpath="/hello"
```

as described in the [Bootstrapping a quarkus project page](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started#bootstrapping-the-project)
fails with the below error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.13.7.Final:create (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.692 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-16T14:23:09+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.13.7.Final:create (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.13.7.Final:create failed: Failed to deserialize extension catalog ~/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-universe-bom-quarkus-platform-descriptor/1.13.7.Final/quarkus-universe-bom-quarkus-platform-descriptor-1.13.7.Final-1.13.7.Final.json: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
[ERROR]  at [Source: (BufferedReader); line: 1, column: 2]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Running the maven debug option (-X) reveals a probably erroneous .m2 repository resource:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.028 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-16T14:10:23+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.13.7.Final:create (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.13.7.Final:create failed: Failed to deserialize extension catalog ~/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-universe-bom-quarkus-platform-descriptor/1.13.7.Final/quarkus-universe-bom-quarkus-platform-descriptor-1.13.7.Final-1.13.7.Final.json: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
[ERROR]  at [Source: (BufferedReader); line: 1, column: 2]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.13.7.Final:create (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.13.7.Final:create failed: Failed to deserialize extension catalog ~/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-universe-bom-quarkus-platform-descriptor/1.13.7.Final/quarkus-universe-bom-quarkus-platform-descriptor-1.13.7.Final-1.13.7.Final.json
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.13.7.Final:create failed: Failed to deserialize extension catalog ~/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-universe-bom-quarkus-platform-descriptor/1.13.7.Final/quarkus-universe-bom-quarkus-platform-descriptor-1.13.7.Final-1.13.7.Final.json
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
```

Looking further at the faulty resource `~/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-universe-bom-quarkus-platform-descriptor/1.13.7.Final/quarkus-universe-bom-quarkus-platform-descriptor-1.13.7.Final-1.13.7.Final.json`, it appears that the expected `.json` file is `html`formatted...

Also, my maven version is compatible with the quarkus requirements:

```
User@-bash - createProject - 14:23:09 $ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.1/libexec
Java version: 11.0.11, vendor: GraalVM Community, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java11-21.1.0/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "11.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

and my local .m2 repository contains all the necessary quarkus dependencies.

- did someone already experienced such an issue ?
- any hint on how to solve this ? (cannot believe that the maven central repository contains an erroneous resource)

Cheers !

Comment: If the json is actually HTML, it may be an error response from the repository server. Can you check? Or even remove files from your local repository to force Maven to download again - e.g. `rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-universe-bom-quarkus-platform-descriptor/`

Comment: Hi Nikos, thanks for jumping in so quickly!

Comment: - deleted the faulty local repo

Comment: - modified my ~/.m2/settings.xml so that it contains the maven central repo

Comment: same error while the faulty file was directly downloaded from central mirror.

Comment: the io/quarkus/quarkus-universe-bom-quarkus-platform-descriptor/1.13.7.Final/quarkus-universe-bom-quarkus-platform-descriptor-1.13.7.Final-1.13.7.Final.json checksum is invalid at download...

Answer (score 2):

Changing my `~/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-universe-bom-quarkus-platform-descriptor/quarkus-universe-bom-quarkus-platform-descriptor-1.13.7.Final-1.13.7.Final.json` with the content of [The expected json descriptor from here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/quarkus/quarkus-universe-bom-quarkus-platform-descriptor/1.13.7.Final/quarkus-universe-bom-quarkus-platform-descriptor-1.13.7.Final-1.13.7.Final.json) solved the issue.

Here is the expected result:

```
User@-bash - createProject - 15:46:04 $ mvn io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.13.7.Final:create -DprojectGroupId=org.acme -DprojectArtifactId=getting-started -DclassName="org.acme.getting.started.GreetingResource" -Dpath="/hello"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.13.7.Final:create (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
-----------

applying codestarts...
 java
 maven
 quarkus
 config-properties
 dockerfiles
 maven-wrapper
 resteasy-example

-----------
[SUCCESS] ✅ quarkus project has been successfully generated in:
--> /Users/User/work/quarkus/test/createProject/getting-started
-----------
[INFO] 
[INFO] ========================================================================================
[INFO] Your new application has been created in /Users/User/work/quarkus/test/createProject/getting-started
[INFO] Navigate into this directory and launch your application with mvn quarkus:dev
[INFO] Your application will be accessible on http://localhost:8080
[INFO] ========================================================================================
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.060 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-16T17:16:26+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I do not know BTW where to report the maven central invalid download checksum for this file.

Comment: If you can verify indeed that any of the checksum files in [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/quarkus/quarkus-universe-bom-quarkus-platform-descriptor/1.13.7.Final/) is wrong, maybe report it to the Quarkus team?