# Creating quarkus project fails on resolving extension catalog

Tags: maven, quarkus

I installed quarkus cli with chocolatey. I also have Zulu 11 installed as my Java 11, as well als maven 3.9.5. These are the requirements needed to create a simple quarkus app when following the tutorial.

I then tried to create a quarkus project with the quarkus cli. However, I get the following output:

```
C:\Users\LeoBre\codebase\quarkustests>quarkus create app
Looking for the newly published extensions in registry.quarkus.io
[ERROR]  Unable to create project: Failed to resolve extension catalog of io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-bom:pom:3.5.0

C:\Users\LeoBre\codebase\quarkustests>quarkus create app --refresh
Looking for the newly published extensions in registry.quarkus.io
[ERROR]  Unable to create project: Quarkus extension registry registry.quarkus.io did not provide any extension catalog

C:\Users\LeoBre\codebase\quarkustests>quarkus create && cd code-with-quarkus
Creating an app (default project type, see --help).
[WARN]  Failed to resolve the Quarkus extension registry descriptor of registry.quarkus.io from public-repository 
(https://[CENSORED PRIVATE URL]/repository/maven-public/) having applied the mirrors and/or proxies from the Maven settings to registry.quarkus.io (https://registry.quarkus.io/maven). Re-trying with the original registry.quarkus.io repository configuration.
Looking for the newly published extensions in registry.quarkus.io
[ERROR]  Unable to create project: Failed to resolve extension catalog of io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-bom:pom:3.5.0
```

When that failed I tried using the maven plugin:

```
C:\Users\LeoBre\codebase\quarkustests>mvn io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.5.0:create -DprojectGroupId=org.acme -DprojectArtifactId=getting-started -Dextensions='resteasy-reactive'
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from public-repository: https://dnp-nexus-01.kscl.dev/repository/maven-public/io/quarkus/platform/quarkus-maven-plugin/3.5.0/quarkus-maven-plugin-3.5.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.822 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-11-03T11:33:44+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.5.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:jar:3.5.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:pom:3.5.0 (absent): Could not transfer artifact io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:pom:3.5.0 from/to public-repository (https://[CENSORED PRIVATE URL]/repository/maven-public/): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

I think the problem might be related to the altered public-repository of my organisation.

At first I thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68003013/quarkus-maven-plugin-fails-to-create-a-project) issue might have been related, but I don't even get as far as him. Have I maybe screwed up something in my quarkus installation? Or is there something else I am mssing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that my company uses custom signed SSL Certificates. They are stored  on the computer, but not in the Java keystore. Adding the option

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT
```

helped. I eventually added it to `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` to not have to add this specific option all the time.